# strophe/xmpp set priority of a client manualy

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe, google-talk

Is there a way to set the priority of a client in Strophe.js manually for an xmpp connection.

I am communicating with a google talk server, and have 2 seperate clients. One client signals the availability status (online/offline/etc...).The other will be for receiving messages regardless of the other clients status.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3921.txt Section 11.1.4

Specifies that

> For message stanzas, the server SHOULD deliver the stanza to the
>   highest-priority available resource (if the resource did not provide a
>   value for the  element, the server SHOULD consider it to
>   have provided a value of zero).  If two or more available resources
>   have the same priority, the server MAY use some other rule (e.g., most
>   recent connect time, most recent activity time, or highest
>   availability as determined by some hierarchy of  values) to
>   choose between them or MAY deliver the message to all such resources. 
>   However, the server MUST NOT deliver the stanza to an available
>   resource with a negative priority; if the only available resource has
>   a negative priority, the server SHOULD handle the message as if there
>   were no available resources (defined below).

So essentially I want to set a negative priority for one client, and a positive priority for the other. This way only one of the clients receives the messages. Is there a way to do this? Or is presence priority purely handled by the server?

Is it as simple as:

```
connection.send($pres({priority: 100}))
```

Comment: So i figured out how to do it: `connection.send($pres()
        .c("priority").t("100")); `

Comment: where "100" is the priority you want to set...